# removeEventListener doesnt work when given inside addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to remove an eventlistener(click) in an element as soon the event is called(i.e, when the element is clicked).

This is what I have done:

```
  ngOnInit() {
     let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
     for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', this.cellClicked.bind(this), false);
     }
  }

  cellClicked(clickedCellEvent) {
      let clickedCell = clickedCellEvent.target.id;
      // disabling clicked cell
      document.getElementById(clickedCell).removeEventListener('click', this.cellClicked.bind(this), 
      false);
   }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="cell" id="0"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="1"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell" id="3"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="4"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell" id="6"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="7"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="8"></td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have a reference to the original function in order to remove it. `this.cellClicked.bind(this)` creates a new, different function so it's not removing the original.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Much thanks for the response. I'm fairly new to Javascript and Angular. Could you please help me out of this by telling how exactly I can have a reference to the original function and remove the evenlistener from the function?